# In matplotlib, how can I plot a time series with the x-axis as isoformat times?

Tags: matplotlib

I can find plenty of examples of plot_date() and the like, but how can I plot a time series where the x-axis is strings as returned by datetime.time.isoformat()?  I am using microsecond data, and that appears to be a serious restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old quesstion, I would still like to point to a more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067368/annotate-time-series-plot-in-matplotlib?rq=1).

Basically, matplotlib can deal on its own with datetime.datetime objects. You can just plug them in as data. To fix your formating, use:

`xfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S:%f')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax.plot(datetimes, data)`

Adjust the format to suite your needs. Formating directives description can be found on [PythonLibrary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) under 8.1.7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DATETICK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datetick.html) command to add date strings to your x axis:

```
>> datetick('x', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS.FFF', 'keeplimits', 'keepticks')
```

You may need to adjust the date format for your purposes and the 'keeplimits' and 'keepticks' options may or may not apply to your application.