# Annotating points from a Pandas Dataframe in Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Given a `DataFrame` like:

```
             LIST_PRICE      SOLD_PRICE
MOYRLD      
1999-03-31   317062.500000   314800
1999-06-30   320900.000000   307100
1999-09-30   400616.666667   366160
1999-12-31   359900.000000   NaN
2000-03-31   359785.714286   330750
```

Using the code:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax3=df5.plot()
ax3.set_ylim(100000,600000)
ax3.set_title('Heatherwood-Quarterly')
```

I generate a plot like:

[image: Heatherwood example]

I cannot figure out how to get the axis to attach an annotation?
This example [Annotate Time Series plot in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067368/annotate-time-series-plot-in-matplotlib) is very close but I don't know how to specify the x and y axis from the `DataFrame`?

So it should be close to:

```
ax3.annotate('Test', (mdates.date2num(x[1]), y[1]), xytext=(15, 15), 
            textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

But what do I use instead of `x[1]` and `y[1]` to get the axis? I tried `['MORLD'][1]` and `['SOLD_PRICE'][1]` and got  `index out of range`...

Comment: loo at the last link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#plotting

Comment: Does not seem that it is using a Dataframe with Dataframe indexing?

Comment: With pandas 0.11.0, and matplotlib 1.2.1 it seems to function properly if you use `ax.annotate('Test', (df5.index[1], df5['SOLD_PRICE'][1]), ...`. At least if the index of your `DataFrame` is a `DatetimeIndex`.

Comment: @nordev Beautiful!! Please post as the answer so I can mark properly! just could not work out the DF index access syntax! Thank you so much

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can access the index values with the `index` attribute of the `DataFrame`. So you can simply use

```
ax3.annotate('Test',
             (df5.index[1], df5['SOLD_PRICE'][1]),
             xytext=(15, 15), 
             textcoords='offset points',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))
```

This gives (based on your sample data) the below output:

[image]