# Getting a sane default date axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib

I am often working interactively in an ipython shell or ipython notebook.
Say, I had a `pandas.DataFrame` with a `DatetimeIndex`, like this:

```
idx = pd.date_range("12:00", periods=400000, freq="S")
df = pd.DataFrame({"temp":np.random.normal(size=len(idx))}, index=idx)
```

In order to plot it, I can simply do:

```
plt.plot(df.temp, '.')
```

[image]

As one can see, neither do I have to specify the x-axis data, as it is nicely inferred from the DataFrame, nor do I have to specify that I actually want the x-axis to be date based. (Gone are the times of `plt.plot_date`)
That's awesome!

But the x-axis looks ugly in two ways:

- the labels overlap and are hard to read.
- the labels show hours instead of dates.

One can *almost* repair this problem like, e.g. like this:

```
plt.plot(df.temp, '.')
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

As one can see in the resulting plot, the leftmost date label is clipped.
[image: leftmost date label is clipped]

So by increasing the code size by 300% one can almost get a nice plot.

---

Now to my question:

I can for my life not remember these 2..3 lines, which I'll have to type in always, when making date based plots. It makes the interface feel clumsy and slow. I always have to google for the solution ...

Can I setup matplotlib in a way, that it kind of remembers what my personal defaults are with regard to date based plotting?

I guess, I could actually hack into the `plot` function. But maybe there is a way using these `matplotlib.rc_params`, which I wasn't able to find.

As I said above, `plt.plot` is going a long way to actually guess what I want. It guesses the x-axis data to be the index of the DataFrame .. and it guesses it should actually plot a date based x-axis instead of a the numerical representation of the dates. How can I *add* something to this?

I'm thinking of maybe even give it some hints like:

```
plt.plot(df.temp, '.', date_fmt='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

or

```
plt.plot(df.temp, '.', autofmt_xdate=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter):

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
#rotates the tick labels automatically
fig.autofmt_xdate()

ax.plot(df["T"], '.')

plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: While the code certainly improves the result *for now*. The answer is not hitting the spot of my question. I will rephrase the question now to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you. Please explain `sane axis labeling`, can you add some sample with desired output?

Comment: You got the part about `sane axis labeling` just right. But I wasn't heading for a one-time answer, but I'm looking for an answer solving it once for all time.

Comment: Hmmm, hard question, bcause I am not matplotlib guru. I do some research and you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13521621/2901002) or 
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11068038/2901002).