# Annotate X-axis labels in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image]

The above image is what I want. Note the red annotation `Big event happend` with an arrow to the X-axis label `2017-12-08`.

My code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'experiment': [1, 2, 3],
        'control': [2, 3, 4],
        'date': ['2017-12-08', '2017-12-09', '2017-12-10'],
    })

    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

    df.plot(x='date', y=['experiment', 'control'])

    plt.show()
```

My result so far

[image]

Comment: You can use plt.annotate.

Comment: You wrote that you want to point at `2017-12-08`, but your drawing points at `2017-12-09`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to use [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) (see docs for lots of cosmetic configuration options):

```
ax = df.plot(x='date', y=['experiment', 'control'])
ax.annotate('Big event happened', 
            xy=(df.date[1], 1), xytext=(3, 15),
            textcoords='offset points', 
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red', shrink=0.05))
```

[image: plot]

Matplotlib is smart enough to handle a datetime format for the `x` coordinate.  You can also use `date2num` to convert to its internal numeric representation of date values, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11068038/2799941).