# Image size of 1005x132589 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot a graph from a Dataframe.

I want to show the height of the bar upon each rectangle and am using `Text()`. For normalising the y-axis, I have taken the log. Below is my code, I am getting error

> Image size of 1005x132589 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction

When I am not using `plt.yscale('log')` then the code is working fine.

According to some suggestions, I have restarted my kernel too, but still getting this issue. Any suggestions regarding this is welcomed.

My Code:

```
# data collected to list. 
list_alarms = df_region.alarmName
# list_east = df_region.EAST
list_west = df_region.WEST
list_north = df_region.NORTH
list_south = df_region.SOUTH


# X-ticks customization
N = len(list_alarms)
xpos = np.arange(N)

# this json file is used to update the style of the plot. 
s = json.load(open('style.json'))    
rcParams.update(s)

# Graph customize
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15,8)
plt.xlabel('AlarmNames at different Regions')
plt.ylabel('Frequency for alarms in MNG-PAN devices')
plt.title('Alarm Generated by MNG-PAN Device at different Regions')
plt.xticks(xpos, list_alarms, rotation = 280)

# bar1 = plt.bar(xpos - 0.3,list_east, width = 0.2, label = 'EAST', color = '#3154C8')
bar2 = plt.bar(xpos - 0.1, list_west, label = 'WEST', color = '#FF9633')
bar3 = plt.bar(xpos + 0.1, list_north, label = 'NORTH', color ='#12B794')
bar4 = plt.bar(xpos + 0.3, list_south, label = 'SOUTH', color ='#EF6FE3')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        if height < 10000:
            plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, 
                 '%d'%int(height),
                 ha = 'center', va = 'bottom', rotation = 90, 
    fontsize=9)


# # autolabel(bar1)
autolabel(bar2)
autolabel(bar3)
autolabel(bar4)

plt.show()
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook, Pandas, Python3.

Answer (score 42):

Check your location variables at `plt.text` line in `autolabel` definition. I had the same problem and I found that the `y` variable I gave to `plt.text` function was too large compared to the value of my dataset of plot.

This is also an issue with `plt.annotate` if the location is outside the figure.

Answer (score 7):

Your X axis might be string values and plt.text() only take scalar values to move on the axis. So that's why your range might be beyond the image size. Convert the x-axis to scalar values. I had same problem, I did the same.

Answer (score 7):

It worked for me using the `transform=ax.transAxes` keyword argument:

for example:

```py
plt.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Some text', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because your x-axis contains dates and when you're adding text, you're passing scalar values.

To solve this, you should convert dates with matplotlib.mdates.date2num()
Refer to this answer:
[Annotate Time Series plot in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067368/annotate-time-series-plot-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 3):

You can adujust pixels and update your update_datalim()

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 14), frameon=False, dpi=100)
fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax = plt.gca()

corners = ((x1, y1), (x2, y2))
ax.update_datalim(corners)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible explanation could be that one of your y-axis values is zero. Thus you could edit your autolabel function into something like this:

```
def autolabel(rects):
for rect in rects:
    height = rect.get_height()
    if (height != 0):
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `plt.gca().text(label)`, as `plt.text(label)` might cause this error too.

Having just spent 3h on

`ValueError: Image size of 1359x269099 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.`, it occoured in a Jupyter Notebook (`.ipynb`), drawing either no output or a stupidly tall image with text on top, BUT NOT in the native matplotlib backend (running a `.py` file).