# Error in Python: image size of 103410x360 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to make a plot in Python and everything seems fine but it I don't know what has happened and how to make it smaller.

Here is the code :

```
 import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as dr
from pandas_datareader import data
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web 

datos=dr.data.get_data_yahoo("SAN",start="2017-01-01",end="2020-12-31")
  
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")


colors = (250, 70, 50), (350, 70, 50)
cmap = sns.blend_palette(colors, input="husl", as_cmap=True)
sns.displot(
    datos,
    x="Date", col="High",  
    kind="ecdf", aspect=.75, linewidth=2, palette=cmap,
)
```

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980366/image-size-of-1005x132589-pixels-is-too-large-it-must-be-less-than-216-in-each

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image size of 1005x132589 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980366/image-size-of-1005x132589-pixels-is-too-large-it-must-be-less-than-216-in-each)

Comment: The code doesn't work because `col="High"` wants to make a new subplot (here `col` stands for subplot column) for each unique value in `datos["High"]`.  You might want to use `y="High"` instead of `col="High"`, but that doesn't work either because *"Bivariate ECDF plots are not implemented"*.