# How can I align text correctly on axv line using matplotlib python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axvline

[image]I am adding an axv line in my python plot and I would like to add text on it. I added to it correctly but the text is overlapping with the axv line. So, **I would like to move it a little backward or forward.** But the problem is I am dealing with dates on x-axis and I couldn't just add some integer values on the x-axis. Please see my codes below and my resulting image.
[image]

```
monthly_death = coup.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = "event_date", freq = "1M"))['fatalities'].sum()

ax = monthly_death.plot(kind = 'line', title = 'testing', figsize=(10, 6))

plt.axvline(x= '2021-09-01', color = 'red', ls = '--')
plt.text ('2021-09-01', 250, 'testing', rotation = 90)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the datestring into the format that [matplotlib uses internally](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib-date-format) and add some offset:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import datestr2num

#sample data
import numpy as np
n = 50
rng = np.random.default_rng(123)
date_range = pd.date_range("2021-01-01", periods=n, freq="3D")
val = rng.integers(0, 1000, size=n)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Dates": date_range, "Values": val})
df = df.set_index("Dates")


ax = df.plot(kind = 'line', title = 'testing', figsize=(10, 6))
d = '2021-04-18'
ax.axvline(x=d, color = 'red', ls = '--')
#convert datestring to number internally used by matplotlib and add an offset value
ax.text(datestr2num(d)+1, 250, 'testing', rotation = 90)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

You should also stick to OOP when starting to use it. You can read about [the differences between pyplot and OOP here](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am getting this following error.

ValueError: Image size of 466793x291 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>

Comment: I wrote basically the same code like you did.
```from matplotlib.dates import datestr2num

monthly_death = coup.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = "event_date", freq = "1M"))['fatalities'].sum()
d = '2021-04-18'
ax = monthly_death.plot(kind = 'line', title = 'Deaths due to political violence')
ax.axvline(d, color = 'red', ls = '--')
ax.text(datestr2num(d)+1, 250, 'testing', rotation = 90)

plt.show()```

Comment: As I obviously cannot reproduce your problem, there is nothing I can contribute.

Comment: I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51980366/8881141), though. Seemingly, your datestring is not correctly interpreted.

Comment: I think the time string is parsed differently from the format produced by datestr2num. That's why it must be getting a value outside the figure. When I first processed the data, I used pd.to_datetime(df['event_date']) to ensure it has the correct type. Then, I used groupby and Grouper to group the data by months. I think it's probably because of Grouper since they are producing only first day of the month etc.