# add count column in time series plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot the mean based on month and years.

My data have two columns (count, mean) and the date as index.

As shown here is a plot similar to my plot where x is years and y is mean

[image]

Here is my code

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    diet = df[['mean']]
    diet.plot(figsize=(20,10), linewidth=5, fontsize=20 ,marker='<')
    plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=20);
    plt.xlabel('Month/Year')
    plt.ylabel('mean')
```

Is there any way to add the count column on the all point line like this to know the count number in each month.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotate Time Series plot in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067368/annotate-time-series-plot-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @DizietAsahi not much, because i want to add column not one word

Comment: Well, you have to run a loop to add one word for each row of your df. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
idx = pd.date_range(start='1901-01-01', end='1903-12-31', freq='1M')
df = pd.DataFrame({"mean": np.random.random(size=(idx.size,)), "count": np.random.randint(0,10, size=(idx.size,))}, index=idx)

plt.figure()
ax = df['mean'].plot(figsize=(8,4))
for d,row in df.iterrows():
    ax.annotate('{:.0f}'.format(row['count']), xy=(d,row['mean']), ha='center')
```

[image]

Comment: your example worked but with my data i got this error `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'`

Comment: Provide a snippet of your dataframe

Comment: i think that because my data is groupby years and month so I have to ungroup

Comment: yes it is like what I thought, so I had to reset the index and it worked thank you